# IOS How to access uipageviewcontroller from its children?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

### I have the below classes, the first contains an instance of UIPageViewController and the second is the view controller of the childs

```
@interface GuidePager : UIViewController     <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageController;
@property NSArray *viewControllers;
- (void)flipToPage:(NSString *)index;

@end
```

AND

```
@interface GuidePagerChild : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end
```

I need to call flipToPage of the GuidePager from GuidePagerChild where GuidePagerChild.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a delegate protocol for the child:

```
@protocol GuidePagerChildDelegate;

@interface GuidePagerChild : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<GuidePagerChildDelegate> delegate;   
@end

@protocol GuidePagerChildDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)guidePagerChild:(GuidePagerChild *)child flipToPage:(NSString *)index
@end
```

Then:

```
@interface GuidePager : UIViewController <
    GuidePagerChildDelegate,  // Add the new protocol to the list.
    UIPageViewControllerDataSource, 
    UIPageViewControllerDelegate
>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageController;
@property NSArray *viewControllers;
- (void)flipToPage:(NSString *)index;

@end
```

Then when you create the child:

```
GuidePagerChildDelegate *child = [[GuidePagerChild alloc] init];  // Or however you create it.
child.delegate = self;  // Assuming you create it from within GuidePager.  If not, get a pointer to GuidePager and set it as the delegate.
```

Then:

```
@implementation GuidePager

...

- (void)guidePagerChild:(GuidePagerChild *)child flipToPage:(NSString *)index 
{
     [self flipToPage:index];
}

...

@end
```

Comment: There are other methods.  You could fire an `NSNotification`, for example.  In general iOS frameworks prefer the delegate pattern.

Comment: Then using the delegate you might prevent releasing the childpage (I ran into this) and using too much memory. I solved it by using notifications.

Comment: Or you could've just solved the memory issue.. If the delegate is weakly referenced and nothing is retaining it there's no reason for a memory leak.